# How to create a DatePicker from class which do not extends Activity, Android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm trying to create DatePicker dialog from a class that doesn't extends the Activity class. I need DatePicker in a class called EnterDate which has Context attribute containing Activity Context.

All examples of DatePicker on the WEB are basic ones written in Activity class and that's why they confusing me.

I want date picker which works good on Android lower then 3.0. I don't use XML layout.

So basically I need suggestion where to put onCreateDialog() , how to retrieve chosen time, etc.

I've Button which have onClickListener() for calling a DatePicker.

An hour ago I've asked a same question for the TimePicker and got this answer:
[How to create a TimePicker from class which do not extends Activity, Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797244/how-to-create-a-timepicker-from-class-which-do-not-extends-activity-android)

I assume that that solution needs only minor modification to work like DatePicker..

Tnx

Comment: I guess you should give some effort for this...If you found any problem then came here...

Comment: Dear Mr. Mohsin, I did! I create very similar class to the one you suggest me in a previous question but have some NumberPicker. java exception in that solution. And Like I told I assume that answer on this question is very similar like the answer on previous. And also, I think it could be useful to other users too. I think that your -1 vote isn't justified. Still appreciate your help... Ivan

Comment: Sorry but Mr. Mohsin is absolutely right.

Comment: @IvanKovac -1 not from myside..:)

Comment: Sorry for accusing you.. Can I give you a medal for you effort? Is there a way I can do this? I must check. You definitely deserve high reputation! Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified class

```
public class MyDatePicker {
DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;


public interface onDateSet {
    public void onDate(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth);
}

onDateSet mOnDateSet;

public void setDateListener(onDateSet mOnDateSet) {
    this.mOnDateSet = mOnDateSet;
}
public MyDatePicker(Context ctx) {
    mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ctx, new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mOnDateSet.onDate(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        }
    }, 2000, 1, 1);
}

public void show() {
    mDatePickerDialog.show();
}
```

and..

```
 public void ShowDatePicker() {
        MyDatePicker myTimePicker = new MyDatePicker(this);
        myTimePicker.show();
    myTimePicker.setDateListener(new onDateSet() {

        @Override
        public void onDate(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "date is " + year + ":" + monthOfYear+":"+dayOfMonth,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Before I post this question I've created a same class like this one with only difference:  mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ctx,..., 2, 1, 1);   And that "2" make that exception. Now, with your code I changed that to 2000 and all works fine.. Thank you very much Mr. Moshin. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need activity for creating and showing dialog. You can just create Dialog with callback and init data with helper class `DatePickerDialog.Builder`, and then call `show()` for this builder.

*This will work only if you are in UI thread.*

Comment: You might want to give him advice about `Activity.runOnUIThread()` as well :)